# I have problem with dropdown nav in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown list by follow code, but in implementation I can't see its sub-item, actually its item "game" in this code doesn't have shown.
Is any other CDN required?
[implementation's pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2by0i.jpg)

```
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   

</head>
```

...................................................

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item  dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Category</a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a  class="dropdown-item" href="#"> game</a>
                        <a  class="dropdown-item" href="#"> tech</a>
                        <a  class="dropdown-item" href="#"> learn</a>

                    </div> 
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Active Listings</a>
        </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dropdown/2.0.3/jquery.dropdown.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

`(bootstrap.min.js) CDN` shouldn't be in `<head>` it's should be at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: tnx for your response. i done it but it didn't work

Comment: i think u use a wrong CDN, take a look here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Comment: finally I used nav tag, but I'll check your recommendation